# Length of vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do you find the length of this vector?

$(5 e^{20}) \mathbf{ \hat i}-e^{-4}\mathbf{ \hat j}+\mathbf{\hat k}$

Every time I try to do this, it turns out very ugly. I need to find the length to solve for the unit tangent vector of $(e^5\mathrm t)\mathbf{ \hat i}+(e^{-1}\mathrm t)\mathbf{ \hat j}+t\space \mathbf{ \hat k}$ at $\mathrm t(4)$. The above vector is the derivative of this one with 4 already plugged.

From what i see in my math book, $T(t)$ is equal to $\frac{the \space derivative}{the\space length\space of\space the\space derivative}$. I'm pretty sure this is how you do it. If anyone could help, it would be very much appreciated... Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the pythagorean theorem. $5e^{20}\textbf i-e^{-4}\textbf j+\textbf k$ has length $\sqrt{(5e^{20})^2+(-e^{-4})^2+1^2}$. It might not be super pretty, but it's not so horrible either: you can expand it out with just a few minutes of extra effort, and then you can even pull the denominator out of the radical.